# Visual Studio Schema Compare Doesn't Handle Variables Properly

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

If I have a variable, say $(someDb) as in

select * from [$(someDb)].[dbo].[SomeTable]

when I do a schema compare and there is another difference in the code, then even these variables get marked as being a difference.

If there is no other difference in the file, fortunately the file is treated correctly.

Is there a way to get the schema compare to work properly in all cases?